# After redirection my $_SESSION is empty, why?

Tags: php, redirect

I run followed test to verify my code working properly:

> curl  -L -i    -X POST   -d 'json={"orderBy":0,"maxResults":50}'  http://mysite.com/ctlClient/

I call: http://mysite.com/ctlClient/index.php:

```
        session_unset();
        session_start();

        //pass data to _SESSION
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
           $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
         }
        // redirect to `/fwf/online/index.php`
        ctlGotoSameDomain("/fwf/online/");
```

After redirect, I call `/fwf/online/index.php`:

```
 <?php

session_start();

 ....

class fwfOnline {


  public function __construct() {

         msqLogFile('test/test_max',$_SESSION);

        // here is my problem, $_SESSION is empty, :(

        $this->json = isset($_SESSION['json']) ? $_SESSION['json'] : null;
        global $gConfig;
        if ($gConfig['soapDebug'])
            msqLogFile("fwf/post", Array('post' => 'Request: '.$this->json));
        $this->response = $this->getResponse();
        echo $this->response;
    }

....
```

In logs from `mysite.com/ctlClient/index.php` I see that $_SESSION has data
but in `/fwf/online/index.php` its empty.

Can someone tell me what did i miss?

Thank you,

**[EDIT]**
From @rr-

I printed both session IDs and got difference:

```
"2013-07-05 09:44:31","Session ID: ihpfs1skrp792gncgancb02516"
"2013-07-05 09:44:31","Session ID: tp6ejtl1tj9bigrgsi3jt6h9a1"
```

why its happened?

**[FIX]**

Regards to `@rr-` answer I found the problem,

I need to add `-b` to my script to enable the cookies. CURL by default doesn't use them and this issue caused to session ID problem.

Thank you `rr-`

Comment: Do you "session_start" in the redirected-to page?

Comment: Are you sure you're redirecting to the exact same domain (no `www.domain.com` vs. `domain.com`)?

Comment: @Paul Yes, I tried to add it, but still doesn't work. I edited mt post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have started session in the target page: `/fwf/online/index.php`.

You can also check return value of `session_id()` on both pages. The value should be the same, if it isn't even though you have called `session_start` on both pages, this can mean three things:

1. Either you call `session_write_close` which effectively leads to creating new sessions and forgets all previous data,
2. PHP cannot access directory where it should store session data on the server (it happens!),
3. ...or user has disabled cookies, thus making his browser unable to keep session ID.

I think the third option is most likely the reason of the problem.

Comment: I printed both sessions IDs and got different names: "Session ID: ihpfs1skrp792gncgancb02516"
"Session ID: tp6ejtl1tj9bigrgsi3jt6h9a1"

Comment: Yes, from Android clients it works but from my script - no, maybe in  cookies problem

Comment: Good shoot mate, it was cookies, I added `-b` option to enable cookies. Thank you, u saved me hours :)